# Exception occurred in target VM: For input string: "1" java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, string

I am a .net developer and just started out with Java development.

```
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    int vertIdx = sCurrentLine.trim().indexOf(space);
    String ver = sCurrentLine.trim().substring(0,vertIdx);
    int vrtInt = Integer.parseInt(ver.trim()); // Here is the error
    //Code Continues
}
```

At Integer.parseInt(ver.trim()), I am getting the following exception:

```
Exception occurred in target VM: For input string: "1" 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at kosaraju.Graph.createGraph(Graph.java:75)
    at kosaraju.Graph.main(Graph.java:247)
```

At this point of execution, my value for sCurretline is "1 4" and ver is "1"
I was not able to figure out the such a small issue. Can someone please point out the bug in my code?

Here is my watch window:

[image]

Comment: Don't post exception in quotes. Use code block (`{}` button on editor) to preserve its formatting. Also please indent your code to make it easier to read and see scope of its fragments.

Comment: Are you sure there are no unprintable characters in string you want to parse? Try printing each character (or preferably its codepoint) like `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(yourString.chars().toArray()));`

Comment: I get this in the debug output window: [65279, 49]. My string has a value of 1

Comment: Are you adding double quotes for readability or they are present in your line being read?

Comment: I added an image of my watch windows to make it clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on result `[65279, 49]` it looks like your text starts with [Zero Width No-Break Space](http://unicode-table.com/en/FEFF/) which can't be trimmed as it is not considered as whitespace, nor parsed as number.

You need to remove it for instance with `replaceAll("[^\\d+-]","")` which will remove any character which is not `digit`, `+` or `-`.

Comment: It worked. But, can you please explain a little bit of the issue. I don't do these kind of replacement in c# code and I am just starting in Java today.

Comment: @PushCode I am not C# developer so I can't tell you why `trim()` there also removes non-break spaces but it seems that Java doesn't thread them as whitecharacters which can be deleted via `trim()`. I am not sure what else can I say. If you need more informations about `replaceAll("[^\\d+-]","")` then it is method which allows us to find match for regular expression, and replace it with something else (in our case with empty string, which means we are removing matched part).

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove characters whith .replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")

```html
br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    int vertIdx = sCurrentLine.trim().indexOf(space);
    String ver = sCurrentLine.trim().substring(0,vertIdx);
    ver=ver.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
    int vrtInt = Integer.parseInt(ver.trim()); // Here is the error
    //Code Continues
}
```